# setting language to ck editor remove toolbar customization of ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

By default ck editor has English language. My requirement is to change the creditor language dynamical according to my input.But after setting language to ck editor, toolbar customization that i have already set got removed.

Here is my js code

```
var g_ckEditorConfig = { toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Undo', 'Redo'], ['TextColor', 'BGColor'], ['Font', 'FontSize'], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']]};**

$('#txtEditor').ckeditor({ language: 'fr' });
$('#txtEditor').ckeditor(function () { }, g_ckEditorConfig);**
```

Can some one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Once you call [`$( selector ).ckeditor()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery-method-ckeditor), a new instance of the editor is created. You got to extend `g_ckEditorConfig` with `{ language: 'fr' }` to combine both things:

```
$( '#txtEditor' ).ckeditor( function () { 
   ...
}, $.extend( true, {}, g_ckEditorConfig, { language: 'fr' } ) );
```

The above uses [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). You can use [`CKEDITOR.tools.extend()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-extend) as well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/LNpQe/).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. i replaced your code  $('#txtEditor').ckeditor(function () { }, $.extend(true, {}, g_ckEditorConfig, { language: 'fr' }));   but it din't work for me. ex: the tool tip of the options are still in english. can you please help me.

Comment: I added [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/LNpQe/) to my answer to prove that it works.